# Trigger page re-rendering before JS intensive calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

How can I force to display an object with jQuery before an long computational JS function? I want to simply display the font-awesome spin wheel before the function starts. When I debug it it works fine because there are breaks between my debug steps, but when I run the page the it does not show the spinwheel but goes straight into the function.

```
$('#waitSpinner').show();
longCalculation();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a callback to the show method so that once the .show() is finished it will execute your next piece of code.

Example:

```
$('#waitSpinner').show('fast', longCalculation);
```

Or you could do this with an anonymous function like so

```
$('#waitSpinner').show('fast', function(){
     longCalculation()
});
```

Comment: You might want to remove the `()` after `longCalculation`.

Comment: Thank you for catching that!

Answer (score 2):

Put your calculation on the event queue:

```
setTimeout(longCalculation, 1);
```

This will allow the redraw before the calculation. You can also look into [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) as a way to perform the calculations in a background thread:

```
var spinner = $('#waitSpinner');
spinner.show();
var worker = new Worker('calculation.js');
worker.onmessage = function (e) {
  console.log('Result is ' + e.data);
  spinner.hide();
};

// calculation.js

longCalculation();
postMessage(calculationResult);
```

Comment: Seems like you'd want `Worker` before `spinner.show()` no?

Comment: I don't think it would matter, @hexalys.